# Googleアナリティクスの表示不具合とPV減少について

Tags: google-analytics

Googleアナリティクスで、
「行動」→「すべてのページ」から主要ページのPVを見ているのですが、
一部のページについてURLが正しく表示されなくなってしまいました。

例えば、example.ne.jp/というページの場合、1/10を境に、
example.ne.jpexample.ne.jp/と、ドメイン名がつながった状態で表示されるようになりました。
PVも1/10を境に急減しています。

何らかの不具合だと思われるのですが、
原因と対処方法についてご存知の方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか。